# How to deduct specific array "values from another values" in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$datas = array(54,12,61,98,88,
               92,45,22,13,36);
```

I want to write a loop which can deduct values of an array like below and show it with echo:

```
$datas[5]-$datas[0]  for this line the result will be 92-54   "38"
$datas[6]-$datas[1]  for this line the result will be 45-12   "33"
$datas[7]-$datas[2] ...                                       "-39"
```

my codes are:

```
<?php
                    $smonth1= 0;
                    $emonth1=5;
                    for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i-- ) {
                        $result = array_diff($datas[$emonth1], $datas[$smonth1]);
                        echo (implode ($result))."<br/>" ;
                        $smonth1++ ;
                        $emonth1++;
                    }
?>
```

but I couldn't get the result I don't know why. I am fresh in php. Can you help me??

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php isn't even close to what you need. Did you actually read the manual for that function?

Comment: Will the array always have 10 items, or can the size vary?

Comment: How about a `for` loop going from 5 to 9 - and then you access the item with the index matching your loop variable - and the one with index = (your loop variable - 5) ...?

Comment: @ADyson. My code is not like this. The array is not like this. It is "not fixed", it can be longer or shorter. My problem is how to deduct two values and show it. I several times used array_diff but It doesn't give me the result.

Comment: Well, again, why do you expect array_diff to help you? It's for comparing whole arrays, not subtracting individual numbers from each other. Read the manual.

Comment: @ADyson. you are right. So how can I subtracted them. I used minus lines $datas([$emonth]-[$smonth]). again I haven't got the result.

Comment: `$datas([$emonth]-[$smonth])` does not work. `$datas[$emonth]-$datas[$smonth]` should be better

Comment: `how can I subtracted them`...subtraction is done using the `-` operator. Your problem seems to be more about how to find the matching items to subtract. This is actually a simple matter of looping - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input array always has an even number of values in it (which I think is the only way this scenario could logically work), then you can simply count how many items are in the array, and then loop through it, taking the `n`th item and subtracting it from the `n+(total / 2)`th item.

```
$data = array(54,12,61,98,88,
               92,45,22,13,36);
               
$halfway = count($data)/ 2;

for ($i = 0; $i < $halfway; $i++)
{
    $j = $i + $halfway;
    echo $data[$j] - $data[$i].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ictDT

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want something like this

```php
<?php

$data = [
    54, 12, 61, 98, 88,
    92, 45, 22, 13, 36
];

$offset = 5;

for ($i = 0; $i + $offset < count($data); $i++) {
    echo $data[$i + $offset] - $data[$i];
    echo "\n"; // or <br/> if you run it in browser
}
```